# Is this code protected against SQL injection attacks?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm just wondering if this code is good against SQL injection attacks. I don't know how to check if is good. Also I would like to know if is good how I'm working or this is just bad practice?

```
<?php 

if (isset($_POST['register'])) {

$username = $_POST["username"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$salt = "Not important";
$password_hash = crypt($password, "$2y$". $salt);

if (strlen($username) > 20) {
    echo "Username is too big";
}elseif (strlen($password) > 32) {
    echo "Password is too big";
}elseif (strlen($email) > 100) {
    echo "E-Mail is too big";
}elseif(strlen($username) == 0 || strlen($password) == 0 || strlen($email) == 0){
    echo "Fill every field";
}
else{
    $sth_username = $dbh->prepare("SELECT username FROM user WHERE username = :username");
    $sth_username->bindParam(":username", $username);
    $sth_email = $dbh->prepare("SELECT email FROM user WHERE email = :email");
    $sth_email->bindParam(":email", $email);
    $sth_username->execute();
    $sth_email->execute();
    if ($result = $sth_username->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
        print $result->username . "The username is already is use";
    }elseif ($result = $sth_email->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
        print $result->email . "That e-mail is already in use";
    }else{
        $sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO user (username, password, email, salt) VALUES (:username, :password, :email, :salt)");
        $sth->bindParam(":username", $username);
        $sth->bindParam(":password", $password_hash);
        $sth->bindParam(":email", $email);
        $sth->bindParam(":salt", $salt);
        $sth->execute();
        $sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO stats (strength,agility,intelligence) VALUES (10,10,10)");
        $sth->execute();

        echo "You have been registered";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Looks good to me

Comment: Since you're using a Blowfish hash, make sure the format is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks O.K. to me as well, as far as the SQL injection goes.

However, I'd suggest checking the return value of `$sth->execute();`, so you capture possible errors (i.e., DB being down).

You might also consider doing a case insensitive search for the existing usernames and e-mails, since "person@gmail.com" is the same address as "Person@GMail.com" and users "Person" and "person" are hard to distinguish.

I think `empty($string)` is more advisable than `strlen($string) == 0`.

Last, but not least, adding a "retype your password" field would be a good security against user mistyping what he wants for a password and then ending with a useless account (or having to use "I forgot my password" before the very first login).

Comment: The people at UX.SE disagree with you on offering "retype your password" (http://ux.stackexchange.com/q/20953/16833)

Comment: @Brian I don't agree with you. Yes, the "retyping the password is bad, without a real explanation" answer is the accepted one, and it got the most votes. However, the other answers and the comments throughout that thread are far from consensus, so I don't see this to be "the people at UX.SE" disagreeing (nor agreeing) with me, or among themselves.